# How do i fix an if statement

Tags: python

I need to do this for a school assignment, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It just keeps saying:

> Line 3: SyntaxError: bad input

I'm not good with python.

```
pizza=input('Do you like pizza?')
Yes=set(['Yes','yes','yea','ye','Yea','Ye','Y','y'])
if pizza == Yes
    print('I like pizza too!')
else
    print('I like pizza.')
```

Comment: you need a colon ':' after if pizza == Yes: and else:

Comment: Maybe you want `if pizza in Yes`? `==` would only be true for an identical set, not a string in the set. And yes, a `:` is needed at the end of any line where the next line starts a block (not just the `if`, but also the `else`)

Comment: There are several problems with the code.  Please repeat your tutorial materials to learn how to punctuate an `if` statement, and to check membership in a list.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: "yeap” “yep” “yup” “yeah” "sure" aren't recognized as positive answers?
I also would use `if pizza.lower() in Yes:` in order to have case insensitive check

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement ends with a colon `:`, and you don't want the value of `pizza` be **equal** to the `set`, you want `pizza` to be `in` the `set`

Also you can use only the lowercase form, and use `pizza.lower()`

```
pizza = input('Do you like pizza?')
yes = set(['yes','yea','ye','y'])
if pizza.lower() in yes:
    print('I like pizza too!')
else
    print('I like pizza.')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here, first `if` and `else` lines need to end with a `:`. So instead of `if condition` you'll want `if condition:`

Second, your yes check is comparing a string to a set of strings. You'll need to use the `in` operator to check if the response is equal to any member of the set

```
pizza = input('Do you like pizza?')
yes = set(['Yes','yes','yea','ye','Yea','Ye','Y','y'])
if pizza in yes: # added : and switch == to in
    print('I like pizza too!')
else: # added :
    print('I like pizza.')
```

However, you can reduce the size of the set by making the comparison case insensitive, by calling `.lower()` on the `pizza` variable

```
yes = set(['yes','yea','ye','y'])
if pizza.lower() in yes:
```

Though what might make the most sense for your usecase is to simply check if `pizza` starts with a `'y'`, and get rid of the `yes` set completey

```
if pizza.lower().startswith('y'):
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a colon at the end of `if pizza == Yes`

And also you need to check whether the answer is in the list of acceptable choices.

So it's `if pizza in Yes:`

Maybe rename pizza into answer

Answer (score 0):

The correct code you want to use is

```
pizza=input('Do you like pizza?')
Yes=['Yes','yes','yea','ye','Yea','Ye','Y','y']
if pizza in Yes:
    print('I like pizza too!')
else:
    print('I like pizza.')
```

You need a colon after the if and else statement as this is the correct Python syntax. However you need to check if the input is in the list so you need the

```
if pizza in Yes:
```

otherwise the program will run but it will only print I like pizza no matter the input.